# Composition with spread objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, factory, composition, spread

I watched a tutorial on composition, and it makes you compose objects like this:

```js
const eater = (state) => ({
  eat(amount) {
    console.log(state.name + ' is eating');
    state.energy += amount;
  }
});

// using a factory
const Dog = (name, energy, breed) => {
  let dog = {
    name,
    energy,
    breed
  };
  return Object.assign(dog, eater(dog));
};

const leo = Dog('Leo', 10, 'Pug');
leo.eat(10); // Leo is eating
console.log(leo.energy); // 20
```

I was wondering if you could do something like that instead, and if there are any downsides to doing it like that:

```js
const eater = {
  eat(amount) {
    console.log(this.name + ' is eating');
    this.energy += amount;
  }
};

const Dog = (name, energy, breed) => {
  let dog = {
    name,
    energy,
    breed,
    ...eater
  };
  return dog;
};

const leo = Dog('Leo', 10, 'Pug');
leo.eat(10); // Leo is eating
console.log(leo.energy); // 20
```

As you can see, instead of creating and assigning a function to the object, with `Object.assign`, I create another object `eater` with a method, then I spread that `eater` object and add it to the `dog` object being created inside the factory.

So, is there anything wrong with doing it like that?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a problem with it.  Would probably make more sense to inherit from a common base class that has `eater()` as a method since it appears the whole reason you have it this way is that you want to share it with other types of objects.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. The whole point of composition is justly to avoid using classes as some people argue that it is the "old way" of doing things.  See the link below : https://tylermcginnis.com/javascript-inheritance-vs-composition/   

still, thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: There's no way you're convincing me this is simpler to write, understand, use and extend than using classes.  Classes don't solve every problem, but they are very simple and well understood and easily extensible for the problems they do work for (which is most problems, btw).

Comment: The two approaches are similar and they get the same end result. In first case you called a method that returned an object and then you assigned it to the dog object. In the second case you spread the object directly to the dog object. There is no difference between Object.assign({}, eater) and {...eater}, just that the latter is easier to read and write.

Comment: Alright, awesome, thank you very much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two approaches are very similar. Both are workable & good ways.

Here are the differences:

- The first approach: `eater` is a factory function

  - New `eater` object and `eat` function is created for each `dog`
  - `eat` method is bound:

    ```
    let leoEat = leo.eat;
    leoEat(10); //works
    ```
- The second approach: `eater` is an object

  - The `eater` object and the `eat` function are reused
  - `eat` isn't bound:

    ```
    const leo = Dog('Leo', 10, 'Pug');
    const animal = {name: 'Animal', energy: 0};
    leo.eat.call(animal, 30); // Animal is eating
    console.log(animal.energy); // 30
    console.log(leo.energy); // 10
    ```
- The third approach (yes, there is!): `Eater` and `Dog` are classes

  - The `eat` function is reused
  - `eat` isn't bound
  - Makes use of prototypes
  - Doesn't support multiple inheritance

```js
class Eater {
  eat(amount) {
    console.log(this.name + ' is eating');
    this.energy += amount;
  }
};

class Dog extends Eater{
  constructor (name, energy, breed) {
    super();
    Object.assign(this, {
      name,
      energy,
      breed
    })
  }
};

const leo = new Dog('Leo', 10, 'Pug');
leo.eat(10); // Leo is eating
console.log(leo.energy); // 20
console.log(leo instanceof Dog) //true
console.log(leo instanceof Eater) //true
```

Comment: The first two approaches are "Object-oriented" as well, so that's not a good distinction. You might want to mention instead that prototype inheritance doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks clarification. I haven't thought of multiple inheritance, and... I think I should read the definition of "OOP".

Comment: Thank you very much to the both of you for taking the time to look at and answer my post ! I appreciate very much and I understand.